# Permission issue on writing file on auto-created directory

Tags: php, apache, file

I'm trying to add generated config files into an automatic generated directory. I'm using PHP 5.4, Apache and Debian 7.8 on this virutal box.

So, as i said in topic, i have no problems, to create new directories, but when i'm trying to add files into this fresh generated directory, it won't work (`Warning: fopen (PATH) failed to open stream: Permission denied in (FreshGeneratedDirectoryPath)`). I'm curios, because if permissions are really bad, why the apache process is able to create a directory, but no file inside? I mean, he's the owner from the directory.

How i create my directory:

```
mkdir(PROJECT_PATH . '/tmp/' . session_id(), 0777);
```

I've tried with the mods 0755, 0775, 0777, 1755, 1775, 1777 so far.

And how i try to create files:

```
fopen(PROJECT_PATH . '/tmp/' . session_id() . '/' . $configType . '.conf', "wb");
```

I've tried "a" instead "wb", but that changes nothing.

Comment: you have to chown the root directory to let apache user be able to create a folder

Comment: Uhm, the folder was created, and the owner is apache:apache. If the same process want to create a file i guess it's apache, too. So that's not my problem..?

Comment: have you manually tried with the full absolute path of the folder?

Comment: My ENV-Var `PROJECT_PATH` includes the full absolute path. It's like `/var/www`

Comment: Have you tried setting the chmod after creating the folder with `chmod()`?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois if you do me a favor and look here:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.mkdir.php
You can see, the second parameter is your chmod.. So why i should repeat this? And i can't do chmod() on a non-existing file.

Comment: I do know that mkdir has such a parameter, but mkdir fails to set the chmod on a shard environment, which is why I asked if you tried setting it manually.

Comment: No, it works pretty fine for me. I can see it right now in my "ls -la" response. Everything was created as i wanted (except the files..)